# Can't update rsyslog

Tags: raspbmc

I was checking if there were any updates for my raspberry, so I ran:
`sudo apt-get upgrade`

There are quite a lot of packages, I installed everything, but when my Raspberry starts to setting up the rsyslog package it hangs up.
I waited for more than 10 minuted, then I killed the process.
I tried again, getting the same result.

Any ideas about that?

Answer (score 2):

Same thing happened to me--then I remembered RaspBMC highly recommends against using `sudo apt-get upgrade`.  Which I assume was also a contributing factor to my install becoming trashed beyond recovery when RaspBMC tried to install updates.  I had to do a clean install to get things behaving properly again.

Update 5/14/13:

The May 2013 update is supposed to fix the issues surrounding `apt-get upgrade`.  I haven't tested it, but supposedly starting with this version of RaspBMC it will be possible to use `apt-get upgrade` without breaking anything